# Properly attaching pictures to an email with google scripts

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, blob, email-attachments

I'm trying to make a script with google forms and sheets to help with the automation and tracking our technicians pictures on the jobsite.

The setup is they take pictures of the jobsite and fill out a google form with the information and attach the pictures there. When the form gets submitted, it runs this script to send an email to a predetermined email that everyone in the office can see.

So far I am able to get the email to send the information from the form besides the pictures.

The information for the attached pictures come in as a drive url that is all dumped into one cell as a string.

`"https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxxx, https://drive.google.com/open?id=yyyyyyyy, https://drive.google.com/open?id=zzzzzzzz"`

I convert this string to an array using  `.split(" ,)` which outputs this.

`[https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxxx, https://drive.google.com/open?id=yyyyyyyy, https://drive.google.com/open?id=zzzzzzzz]`

I then iterate through the array and use`.slice(33)` to get rid of the url so all that I'm left with is the drive id (there is probably a better way of doing this but it works for now).

`[xxxxxxxx, yyyyyyyy, zzzzzzzz]`

This is the part where I'm having trouble.
I then iterate agian through that array and grab the driveID and the get the file as a JPEG.
I then use `.push` to put it into another array that I'm using to attachment them to the email.

The issue is that I think I'm not doing this step properly by not pushing the correct thing into the array and/or assuming that `MailApp.sendEmail` can even take an array for attachments.
I'm also not entirely sure how `[Blobs]` work and how to use them properly and that's probably where I'm getting stuck.

Again, this is code is made with very little experience and could probably be optimized futher but at the moment, I just need to have it attach the pictures properly to show that it works.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //for testing purposes
  var values = e.namedValues;
  //gets the form's values
  var pureValues = e.values;

  //sets the values
  var email = pureValues[1];
  var woNum = pureValues[2];
  var firstN = pureValues[3];
  var lastN = pureValues[4];
  var desc = pureValues[5];
  var superDuperRawPics = pureValues[6];

  //splits the picture urls into an array
  var superRawPics = superDuperRawPics.split(", ");

  //slices the url part off to get the drive ID
  var i, rawPics =[]
  for (i = 0; i < superRawPics.length; ++i) {
    rawPics.push(superRawPics[i].slice(33))
       }

  //takes the array of ID's and gets the drive file
  var j, picAttach =[]
  for (j = 0; j < rawPics.length; ++j) {
    var driveID = DriveApp.getFileById(rawPics[j]);
    var drivePic = driveID.getAs(MimeType.JPEG);
    picAttach.push(drivePic);
  }

  //sets the subject of the email to be Jobsite Pictures and the work number
  var subject = "Jobsite Pictures" + " " + woNum;

  //sets the body of the email
  var body = "Technician: " + email + " \n" + 
             "WO#: " + woNum + " \n" + 
             "Customer: " + firstN + " " + lastN + " \n" + 
             "Description: " + desc;

  //for checking if the vars are set correctly
  Logger.log(superDuperRawPics);
  Logger.log(superRawPics);
  Logger.log(rawPics);
  Logger.log(picAttach);
  Logger.log(subject);
  Logger.log(body);

  //sends email to me with the new info
  MailApp.sendEmail('example@domian.com', subject, body, {attachments: [picAttach]});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to attach them then use [options attachments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Comment: Does the last line not attach the pictures to the email?
`MailApp.sendEmail('alex@laconiares.com', subject, body, {attachments: [picAttach]});`

Comment: should probably be {attachments: picAttach}  what came from the form...urls?

Answer (score 0):

I was being dumb and added brackets to the `attachments:` when it didn't need them.

The correct way is this.

`MailApp.sendEmail('example@domian.com', subject, body, {attachments: picAttach});`

Changing this has the script sending emails with the pictures attached.